# make a radio button selection defualt not selecting based on value

Tags: angular

I am attempting to make a button from a group of radio buttons by default to be selected based on the value given to the radio buttons, the individual radio buttons have value but the selection by value is not happening.

Here are my snippets for assistance:

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input [(ngModel)]="logisticsData.type"  
    type="radio" name="logistics" checked="checked" id="100" [value]="100" 
    [checked]="logisticsData.type == '100'">
    <label for="100">Logistic 1</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input [(ngModel)]="logisticsData.type" 
    type="radio" name="logistics" id="101" [value]="101" 
    [checked]="logisticsData.type == '101'">
    <label for="101">Logistic 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input [(ngModel)]="logisticsData.type"
    type="radio" name="logistics" id="102" [value]="102" 
    [checked]="logisticsData.type == '102'">
    <label for="102">Logistic 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input [(ngModel)]="logisticsData.type" 
    type="radio" name="logistics" id="103" [value]="103" 
    [checked]="logisticsData.type == '103'">
    <label for="103">Logistic 4 </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the moment, **logisticsData.type** has a value of 103, but the button is not selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code should be like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="field">
    <div *ngFor="let list of data; let idx = index" class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="logisticsData" name="radiogroup" [checked]="list.id === 102" [value]="list.id" />{{ list .description }}
        <label for="102">{{list.label}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS Code**

```
logisticsData = 102;
data = [ {id: 101, description: '101', label: 'Logistic 1' }, {id: 102,description: '102', label: 'Logistic 2'}, {id: 103,description: '103', label: 'Logistic 3'} ];
```

Note:- You can set **checked** attribute of angular `[checked]="list.id === 102"` && you can default assign using ts code like this `logisticsData = 102;`

**Second Example for the hardcode HTML**

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input [(ngModel)]="logisticsData" type="radio" name="logistics" checked="checked" id="101" value="101" />
    <label for="101">Logistic 1</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input [(ngModel)]="logisticsData" type="radio" name="logistics" id="102" value="102" />
    <label for="101">Logistic 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input [(ngModel)]="logisticsData" type="radio" name="logistics" id="103" value="103" />
    <label for="102">Logistic 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input [(ngModel)]="logisticsData.type" type="radio" name="logistics" id="104" value="104" />
    <label for="104">Logistic 4 </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ts Code**

```
logisticsData = '102';
```

Comment: can u please modify your solution using the snippets I proposed, u are making iterations and I am not, thanks

Comment: @Blaze, Hope this helps you. :-)

Comment: I think the issue was with `value` && `[value]`. when you use hardcode HTML you need to use simple HTML attribute value && when you use iteration you need to use `[value]`

Comment: the fix worked, this - [value] has kept me bottled up, thanks